# Upload picture to server

Tags: java, android, image, upload, camera

I am using the following code:
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

IT WORKS!

I want know that the picture I will send is a picture taken a few seconds ago with the camera. 
So.. I've created a simple method to take the picture and then this OnActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        //2
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        //3
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        //4
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "guasto.jpg");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //5
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();

         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName); //this should call the working method to upload the picture

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the upload won't work and it stops right before executing this line of code:

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
```

What should I do to resolve the problem...? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code. Create an async task and add the code in doInBackground method. You will get InputStream's object in return.

You should use Multipart entity.

```
        File file = new File(selectedImage);
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/*");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart(RequestParams.POST, cbFile);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://yourwebserveraddress.com/apiname_or_whatever_path_it_is");

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Where  selectedImage is a path of your image.